# Le sens de l'expression « mon petit doigt me/m'a dit » varie-t-il selon le temps du verbe employé ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, temps-grammatical, fréquence-utilisation, évolution-récente

Un [*ngram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=petit%20doigt%20me%20dit%2Cpetit%20doigt%20m%27a%20dit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpetit%20doigt%20me%20dit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpetit%20doigt%20m%27a%20dit%3B%2Cc0) montre une augmentation de la fréquence de l'emploi au présent depuis peu ; on ne sait pas ce que ça veut dire et il n'est pas clair que les résultats illustrent une différence.

---

Le sens de la locution *mon petit doigt me/m'a dit* varie-t-il selon le temps du verbe employé (présent, passé composé) ; le cas échéant est-ce récent, est-ce une extension ou une évolution du sens de l'expression ?

Answer (score 1):

J'ai la même intuition que toi, c'est à dire que le passé signifie "*on m'a dit (mais je ne vais pas dire qui) que ...*" et le présent signifie "*j'ai le sentiment que ...*".

Je n'explique pas la montée récente de la forme au présent récemment dans ngram, surtout que les résultats google ne semblent retourner que des résultats utilisant le passé. J'aurais tendance à dire que la forme au passé reste plus courante.

Pour ce qui est de l'origine, on peut trouver une réponse dans le lien Wiktionary que tu as donné : pour la forme au présent, la partie étymologie indique "From Molière". En effet, dans L'Avare, le personnage d'Aragon y fait référence dans (au moins) [une scène](http://clicnet.swarthmore.edu/litterature/classique/moliere/mi/mi.II.8.html), de manière très littérale :

> Prenez-y bien garde, au moins; car voilà un petit doigt qui sait tout, et qui me dira si vous mentez.

> Voilà mon petit doigt pourtant qui gronde quelque chose. (*Il met son doigt à son oreille.*) Attendez. Eh! Ah! ah! Oui? Oh! oh! Voilà mon petit doigt qui me dit quelque chose que vous avez vu, et que vous ne m'avez pas dit.

Une autre raison qui peut expliquer cette différence de sens est la proximité avec l'expression "*Quelque chose me dit que ...*", qui est bien connue et qui a le même sens. Il n'a qu'un pas à franchir pour que le "quelque chose" deviennent un petit doigt.

Comment: Et pourquoi pas: m'avait dit?